# Empty span width in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have span with `contenteditable` property. Most of the time the span is empty so I set fixed width to the span.

It works good in Opera and chrome I can click on the span and edit data. But with Firefox span behaves like there is no span.

E.g. When the span is empty in Firefox it doesn't appear as editable and I cannot click on it. When only one character is there, like space or something, then I can edit it. I tried to fixed that with html character `&nbsp;` but nothing.

```
$comment = `&nbsp;`

<span class="edit_notes" contenteditable=true onFocus="clear_input('.$data['ID'].')" style="min-width: 1200px; display: inline-block;display:-moz-inline-box;" id="comment'.$data['ID'].'" onBlur="changeComment('.$data['ID'].')"> '.$comment.' </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FF you may use a pseudo element to give it some size or use the `:empty` pseudo class if there is no white-space in HTML produced by server when there's no data to print.

Example below to test:

```css
span[contenteditable][onFocus]:after, span[contenteditable]:empty {
  content:'';
  padding:0.5em;
  }
```

```html
<span class="edit_notes" contenteditable=true onFocus="" style="min-width: 1200px; display: inline-block;" id="comment'.$data['ID'].'" onBlur=""> </span>
<hr/>
<span contenteditable=true ></span>
```

Comment: Like a boss ;) thanks, works - I decreased padding to 0.05 because the line was too large.